# Find ancestors of node in BST in Standard ML

Tags: binary-search-tree, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to find the parent and grandparent of a node in a BST in SML.

I have tried to modify this function:

```
fun search(tree : bst, compare, (data) = 
    let fun s(Leaf) = NONE
          | s(Node{data=nodedata,left=left,right=right}) = 
                (case compare(data,nodedata) of
                      LESS    => s(left)
                    | GREATER => s(right)
                    | EQUAL   => SOME (Node{data=nodedata,left=left,right=right}))
     in
         s(tree)
     end
```

by changing the format of the input, the comparison and the output:

```
fun search(tree : bst, compare, (data) = 
 let fun s(Leaf) = NONE   
 |s(Node{data=nodedata,left=Node{data=nodedata1,left=left1,right=right1},right=right}) =                          
       (case compare(data,nodedata) of
           LESS    => s(left)
           | GREATER => s(right)
           | EQUAL   => SOME nodedata)
```

Obviously it's not working and I suppose there is a simpler way to do this.

I added a new variable in order to save the current father of each node I'm checking and it works, however it's difficult (for me) to find a way to also keep the grandfather of the node I check.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I editted my post with what I've tried

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your search function was not working properly, so I cleaned it up a little bit. In order to avoid unbound type variable in type declaration error, you have to define your `bst` type as `'a bst`. I also fixed a paranthesis error. Here is my version of your `search` function:

```
datatype 'a bst = Leaf | Node of {data: 'a, left: 'a bst, right: 'a bst}

(*search(tree, compare, key) = t
    where t = the tree which has `key` as its root
  *)
fun search(tree : 'a bst, compare : ('a * 'a -> order), key : 'a)
          : 'a bst option = 
  let 
    fun s(tree: 'a bst) : 'a bst option =
      case tree of
        Leaf => NONE
      | Node({data=x, left=l, right=r}) =>
          case compare(key,x) of
            LESS    => s(l)
          | GREATER => s(r)
          | EQUAL   => SOME tree
   in
       s(tree)
   end
(*Example:
search(Node({data=5,
             left=Node({data=3,
                        left=Node({data=2,left=Leaf,right=Leaf}),
                        right=Node({data=4,left=Leaf,right=Leaf})}),
             right=Leaf}),
       Int.compare,
       3);
*)
```

Since you want a function that returns the parent and grandparent nodes of your search, you need a function that returns a tuple of these: (search node, parent of the search node, grandparent of the search node). However, you will not always have a parent or grandparent. For example, if the key you are looking for is already at the root of your main tree, you will not have a parent or grandparent. Because of that, you need to use the `option` type. This will help you return `NONE` as the parent node if there is no parent node for that search. Now, all you need to do is to start the search with (your main tree, `NONE`, `NONE`) and then as you move along the tree, shift the parent nodes to the right. If you don't find the key, just return a triplet of `NONE`. Here is the code for that:

```
(*searchParent(tree, compare, key) =
    (t, the parent of t, the grandparent of t)
    where t = the tree which has `key` as its root
  *)
fun searchParent(tree : 'a bst, compare : ('a * 'a -> order), key : 'a)
                : ('a bst option * 'a bst option * 'a bst option) = 
  let 
    fun s(tree: 'a bst, par: 'a bst option, gpar: 'a bst option)
         : ('a bst option * 'a bst option * 'a bst option) =
      case tree of
        Leaf => (NONE, NONE, NONE)
      | Node({data=x, left=l, right=r}) =>
          case compare(key,x) of
            LESS    => s(l, SOME tree, par)
          | GREATER => s(r, SOME tree, par)
          | EQUAL   => (SOME tree, par, gpar)
   in
       s(tree, NONE, NONE)
   end

(*Example:
searchParent(Node({data=5,
             left=Node({data=3,
                        left=Node({data=2,left=Leaf,right=Leaf}),
                        right=Node({data=4,left=Leaf,right=Leaf})}),
             right=Leaf}),
       Int.compare,
       4);
*)
```

I hope I could help. Please ask if you have any other questions on this issue or code.

Answer (score 0):

While joom's answer is probably sufficient, I find it a little verbose. Here is an attempt to write a shorter interpretation of and answer to the problem: Having a BST and an element `x`, find the two elements `(SOME parent, SOME grandparent)` if they exist.

The strategy I will use is this: Whenever a recursive call is made, record `parent` as the element that was just visited and `grandparent` as the previous parent. If/when an element is found that is `EQUAL` to `x`, return the currently available `(parent, grandparent)`.

Because these two additional variables are not part of the original search function's signature, and because I don't want them to be, the local function `helper` is made.

```
datatype 'a bst = Node of 'a * 'a bst * 'a bst
                | Leaf

fun search (initTree, compare, x) =
  let fun helper (tree, parent, grandparent) =
          case tree of
              Leaf           => (NONE, NONE)
            | Node (y, L, R) => case compare (x, y) of
                                    LESS    => helper (L, SOME y, parent)
                                  | GREATER => helper (R, SOME y, parent)
                                  | EQUAL   => (parent, grandparent)

  in helper (initTree, NONE, NONE) end
```

Testing this function using the following BST:

```
val t = Node (5, Node (3, Node (2, Leaf, Leaf),
                          Node (4, Leaf, Leaf)),
                 Node (7, Node (6, Leaf, Leaf),
                          Node (8, Leaf, Leaf)))
```

We see the expected results:

```
- search (t, Int.compare, 2);
> val it = (SOME 3, SOME 5) : int option * int option
- search (t, Int.compare, 3);
> val it = (SOME 5, NONE) : int option * int option
```

Unfortunately, this function will not tell whether an element was found in the root of the BST or did not exist. That is because `(NONE, NONE)` is returned in both cases.

Comment: I used a record for the binary search tree, because that was how the question was, but using a tuple was what I would do, and what the OP should do, so thank you. Explicitly writing all types is just a choice though.

Comment: Tuples are a little easier to read than records. Records are useful once you get many fields, in which case you often want to pattern match *some* of them, e.g.: `val { foo = x, ...} = r` where `...` actually works. But ideally, one wants a combinatorial way to access fields, like Haskell's lenses.

Explicitly writing all types makes the code a little less readable. Rather, I'd use separate signatures.